# Как в Android приложении проверить активность Google подписки?

Tags: android, in-app-purchases, android-billing

В приложении есть возможность покупать подписки. Я получаю список покупок, но как мне определить активная ли подписка в данный момент (не истек ли ее срок действия)?

Comment: Дополните вопрос: Вы хотите получать информацию по подписке программно, у Вас есть некое api к приложению, Вы обращаетесь к Google-аккаунту через api или к приложению? По возможности дайте больше информации о приложении.

Comment: @Dejsving я работаю через BillingClient

Comment: Возможно это Вам поможет получить информацию о подписках, покупках, позвонив по следующему API: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/get (Purchases.subscriptions: get) и получив ответ , извлечь нужное: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions#resource (Response)

Comment: @Anton перед запросом нужно сделать авторизацию?

Comment: Ну если сделать фейковый запрос, и посмотреть ответ, можно увидеть значения у ключей :  Login Required